# i need pagination with sortBy in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

I have 3 tables `products`, `prices`, `cats`.

I need to filter `product` by `cats` and sort by `price` but I have a problem:

this code work very well but needs pagination.

```php
$products = Product::with('photo', 'price', 'brand')
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($q) use ($cat) {
        $q->where('cat_id', $cat->id);
    })
    ->get()
    ->sortByDesc(function($query) {
        return $query->price->price;
    });
```

at first I did it like this:

```php
$products = Product::with('photo', 'price', 'brand')
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($q) use ($cat) {
        $q->where('cat_id', $cat->id);
    })
    ->paginate($page)
    ->sortByDesc(function ($query) {
        return $query->price->price;
    });
```

but `links()` did not work.

After i did it like this:

```php
$products = Product::with('photo', 'price', 'brand')
    ->whereHas('cats', function ($q) use ($cat){
        $q->where('cat_id', $cat->id);
    })
    ->paginate($page);

$products->setCollection(
    $products->sortBy(function ($query) {
        return $query->price->id;
    })
);
```

but `sortBy` does not work.

so I can't use `orderBy()` by join prices table

because when I do it I can show all products and I can't filter product by categories

my mind does not work, if someone can to help me, I will be very grateful

Comment: Make sure to use `orderBy()` before `paginate()`

Comment: You can use orderBy as `orderBy('prices.id',  'DESC')` something like `Product::with('photo','price','brand')->whereHas('cats', function($q) use($cat){ $q->where('cat_id',$cat->id);})->orderBy('prices.id', 'ASC')->paginate($page);`

Comment: before i test it orderBy('prices.id',  'DESC') but i have error   Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'prices.id' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where exists (select * from `cats` inner join `cat_product` on `cats`.`id` = `cat_product`.`cat_id` where `products`.`id` = `cat_product`.`product_id` and `cat_id` = 3) order by `prices`.`id` asc limit 1 offset 0)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also do:

```
Product::join('price', 'price.id', '=', 'photo.price_id')
                ->orderBy('price.price', 'asc')
                ->select('photo.*')
                ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: it does not work, i did explain it in my question, of course your code have a proplem too